# how to run macro with ActiveX

Tags: excel, vba, activex

I would like to assign a macro, but I keep getting an error:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim wsAccess As Workspace
    Dim dbAccess As DAO.Database
    Dim dbdBase As DAO.Database
    Dim dbODBC As DAO.Database
    'Create the Access workspace
    Set wsAccess = DBEngine(0)
    'Print the details for the default database
    Debug.Print "Access Database "; wsAccess.Databases.Count & _
    "-" & CurrentDb.Name
    'Open a Microsoft Access database -shared -read-only
    Set dbAccess = wsAccess.OpenDatabase("C:\Temp\db1.accdb", False, True)
    Debug.Print "Access Database "; wsAccess.Databases.Count & _
    "-" & dbAccess.Name
    'Clean up
    wsAccess.Close
    Set dbAccess = Nothing
    Set dbdBase = Nothing
    Set dbODBC = Nothing
    Set cn = Nothing
    Set wsAccess = Nothing
End Sub
```

What i did wrong ? evertime when i click run im getting error "User definied type not definied"and shown wsAccess As Workspace
I have selected Activex object but i can't click DAO Microsoft.

Comment: Do you have the required libraries checked under tools-references?

Comment: Which one excatly?

Comment: If I'm not wrong it's the DAO Object library

Comment: I cant. When on reference i trying select and click ok i got some error about dll loading

Comment: Then there is your problem... There I can't help you, sorry